# Using xpath in C#, I need to check both for the existence and value of an element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

The xml doc contains "section" elements which, in turn contain "tag" elements. The xpath needs to check whether or not a section contains a tag named 'SALE_FIN_CONCSSN'. If it does, the tag must not have the value 'Listing'. If every section contained a SALE_FIN_CONCSSN tag, it would be easy to check the value, but that is not the case. A section may contain a SALE_FIN_CONCSSN tag with a different value or no SALE_FIN_CONCSSN tag at all. Here is one thing I tried, but it doesn't filter out the sections with SALE_FIN_CONCSSN tag = 'Listing'.

```
xpath = "Report/data/section[" +
    "@type='salescomp'" +
    " and (tag[@name!='SALE_FIN_CONCSSN'] or tag[@name='SALE_FIN_CONCSSN']/text()!='Listing')" +
    " and tag[@name='GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE.1']/text()!='Active'" +
    "]/tag[@name='GS_GROSS_ADJ_PERCENT.1']";

XmlNodeList percents = xDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

`//section[@type='salescomp' and ((tag[@name='SALE_FIN_CONCSSN' and text()!='Listing']) or tag[@name!='SALE_FIN_CONCSSN'])]`

I haven't tested it yet. Could you put the link of the page?

Comment: Unfortunately, the sample xml that I'm using contains a lot of confidential info, so I can't link to it. Here's a very abbreviated version.

Comment: <Report>
        <data>
            <section type="salescomp" number="4" name="COMP_SALES_4">
                <tag name="GS_AGE.1">65</tag>
                <tag name="GS_GROSS_ADJ_PERCENT.1">9.4</tag>
            </section>     
            <section type="salescomp" number="5" name="COMP_SALES_5">
                <tag name="GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE.1">Active</tag>
                <tag name="SALE_FIN_CONCSSN">Listing</tag>
                <tag name="GS_GROSS_ADJ_PERCENT.1">10.3</tag>
            </section>
        </data>
    </Report>

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work with the SALE_FIN_CONCSSN tag. Here's the xpath that I used:

    xpath = "ACI-Report/appraisal/data/form[@primary='true']/section[" +
  "@type='salescomp'" +
  " and (tag[@name != 'SALE_FIN_CONCSSN'] or (tag[@name = 'SALE_FIN_CONCSSN' and text() != 'Listing']))" +
  "]/tag[@name='GS_GROSS_ADJ_PERCENT.1']";

Comment: But when I try it with a different tag -- GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE.1 -- it returns both of the above sections, even though the second second has GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE.1 set to 'Active'. I can't figure out what the difference is. The tags seem to have exactly the same form.

    xpath = "ACI-Report/appraisal/data/form[@primary='true']/section[" +
  "@type='salescomp'" +
  " and (tag[@name != 'GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE.1'] or (tag[@name = 'GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE.1' and text() != 'Active']))" +
  "]/tag[@name='GS_GROSS_ADJ_PERCENT.1']";

Comment: Are you sure the text only contains the text 'Active'? Or does it have a space before or after it? try using contains() or starts-with() instead of using the exact values. example `contains(@name,'GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE')`

Comment: There are no spaces. I tried contains, but I'm not sure how to use it in this context. The program complains that it needs to return nodes.

Comment: I never did figure out why this wasn't working with GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE, but I found out I could get by with just the results from SALE_FIN_CONCSSN, so that'll be good enough. Thanks for your help. You had some good suggestions and I learned a bit more about xpath.

Comment: `ACI-Report/appraisal/data/form[@primary='true']/section[@type='salescomp' and (tag[not(start-with(@name, 'GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE'))] or (tag[starts-with(@name, 'GS_DATE_TIME_O_SALE') and text() != 'Active']))]/tag[starts-with(@name,'GS_GROSS_ADJ_PERCENT')]`